# Integrando API Google Calendar com Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-calendar

Estou tentando utilizar os componentes REST para fazer uma requisição HTTP com o método POST para inserir um calendário na API, mas a minha requisição está retornando o erro "400 - Bad Request" e antes estava caindo no erro 401 Não autorizado Eu nem mexi no código, não consigo entender essa API.

Estou tentando incluir o token na requisição, mas não sei se estou fazendo de maneira correta. Como posso corrigir isso? Alguém que já integrou essa API no Delphi pra me ajudar?? por favooor

Meu código atual

```
procedure TOAuth2TesterFrm.incluir_btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
json,outro_json,token: String;
begin
token:=AccessTokenEdt.Text;
json:=(
'{"kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry", "etag": "0", "id": "iago21092020@gmail.com", ' +
'"summary": "Calendario Outro", "description": "Descrição do evento", '   +
'{"date": "2020 August 11", "dateTime": "2020-08-11T17:35:36+03:00"}'+
'"timeZone": "Brasília-DF", "colorId": "15", "backgroundColor": "#9fc6e7", "foregroundColor": "#000000", ' +
'"selected": true, "accessRole": "owner", "primary": true, '+
 '"defaultReminders": [{"method": "popup", "minutes": 30}, {"method": "email", "minutes": 10}], '  +
'"notificationSettings": {"notifications": [{"method": "email", "type": "eventCreation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventChange"}, {"method": "email", "type": "eventCancellation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventResponse"}]}}');
outro_json:='{"summary": "Batata"}';
try
    client.ResetToDefaults;
    request.ResetToDefaults;
    response.ResetToDefaults;

    client.BaseURL:='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/';
    response.ContentType := 'application/json';
    request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    request.Body.ClearBody;
    request.AddBody(outro_json);
    client.AcceptEncoding:='utf-8';
    client.ContentType:='application/json';
    request.Resource := 'calendars';
    request.Params.AddHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
    request.Params.ParameterByName('Authorization').Options := [poDoNotEncode];


    request.Execute;
    ShowMessage(request.Response.StatusCode.ToString);
finally
  request.Free;
      response.Free;
      client.Free;

end;
  end;
```

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth) acredito que precise chamar a API de autenticação primeiro, apenas dei uma olhada na documentação não procurei implementar ainda

Comment: Olá, tente fazer utilizando o RESTRequest4Delphi, é bem mais simples e fácil de usar. Talvez te ajude... https://github.com/viniciussanchez/RESTRequest4Delphi